# Solana devnet/testnet NFT marketplace

Tags: solana, nft

Is there a devnet/testnet marketplace in Solana that allows to test before production?

Like an equivalent of [testnet OpenSea](https://testnets.opensea.io/) .

Comment: Unlike opensea on solana magic eden is invite only, open sea indexes all nft contracts and now it supports solana in beta

Comment: Opensea documents were clear about not supporting devnet solana, can you point me to link?

Comment: Yea i think its not there yet but you can test using the phantom wallet itself

Comment: Or create your own auction house on devnet https: //docs.metaplex.com/auction-house/definition

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a deployment of any NFT marketplace to Solana Devnet at this time. You can deploy [auction house](https://docs.metaplex.com/auction-house/getting_started) yourself to test an NFT marketplace implementation.

Comment: This link is outdated and no longer leads to instructions

Would be nice to have a proper dev environment to test stuff without having to deploy...